# How do I update EJS template + AJAX?

Tags: ajax, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I can't get my head around ejs combined with AJAX. When I read about AJAX , most of the tutorials are using an API which will respond with a json objects.

Here's the code

router.js

```
router.get('/jobs', function(req, res) {
    Job.find({}, function(err, jobs) {
        res.render('main/job', {
            jobs: jobs,
            message: req.flash('message')
        });
    });
});
```

custom.js

```
$(function() {


  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/jobs',
    success: function(jobs) {
     // What should I do here?
    }
  });
});
```

EJS template

```
<div class="col-md-4">
       <% for(i=0 ; i < jobs.length; i+=3)  { %>

          <div>
            <h4><%= jobs[j].title %></h4>

          </div>
        <% } %>
      </div>
```

How do I constantly update the ejs using AJAX? because Im quite confused with `res.render();` its not a json object

Answer (score 4):

When you call `res.render()`, you are telling Express to look up a template (in this case, EJS), and "compile" it using some custom data. It then sends the compiled HTML back in the response to the request. In other words, your API does not serve JSON; it serves server-rendered HTML.

On the client side, you can just insert this HTML where you want it in the DOM:

```
$.get('/jobs', function(html) {
  $('#jobs-container').html(html);
});
```

An alternative method would be to serve only JSON from the API, and then render all the HTML on the side of your browser. In this model, you can throw out your server-side EJS template:

```
// router.js
router.get('/jobs', function(req, res) {
  Job.find(function(err, jobs) {
    res.send(jobs);
  });
});
```

On the client:

```
// custom.js
$.get('/jobs', function(jobs) {
  var $jobs = $('<div class="col-md-4"></div>');
  jobs.forEach(function(job) {
    $jobs.append(`<h1>${job.title}</h1>`);
  });
  $('#jobs-container').html($jobs);
});
```

There are many considerations to take when choosing to render your HTML on the client vs. server. [This](http://openmymind.net/2012/5/30/Client-Side-vs-Server-Side-Rendering/) article by Karl Seguin is a good starting place on the subject.

Comment: Sorry, I've been writing in ES6 syntax a lot. I changed back to regular funciton syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but res.json is doing what you probably want. The [documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html) have it all covered.

```
router.get('/jobs', function(req, res) {
    Job.find({}, function(err, jobs) {
        if (req.xhr) { // request was AJAX (XHR)
            res.json({error: err, jobs: jobs});
        } else { // render html template instead
            res.render('main/job', {
                jobs: jobs,
                message: req.flash('message')
            });            
        }
     });
});
```